# Error while installing Xamarin.Auth on visual studio 2015 community

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

While installing Xamarin.Auth Nuget i am getting following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Validation 2.0.4.14103'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.         0

Comment: Are you still experiencing this?I just brought this up to the person at Xamarin who maintains Xam.Auth. If still experiencing, feel free to file an issue on the github repo at: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by updating the Nuget Package for 'Validation' to 2.3.7 which was then installed to the iOS project without issue.

I was then able to install Xamarin.Auth to the iOS project.

Comment: Nice one, simple solution. Shame the NuGet packages themselves don't create this dependency and install it for you!